# Remove color of the background

Tags: android, android-layout

i've implemented a @drawable/file (file being a xml file) and i'm trying to use it as a child- view  background knowing that the parent-view has already a background so that when looking at the child , we can see the parent background . How can i in this file set the color to null? thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@color/black" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:left="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

This is what i 've tried  how can i  set the attribute color to "no-color"

Here is the image , i still get the black background color but i want the background to be completely transparent :

[image]

Comment: you can use transparent color .

Comment: Can you post a screen of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti , here is the image

Comment: @AdityaNandardhane,here is the image , i've already test this solution

Comment: @PatrickRenaud you are applying the transparent color to the left 2dp rect. The other rect is black.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti , it works but one problem appeared now .. I want the left side to be black when increasing the density to like 10dp , it doesn't show a change

Answer (score 0):

use transparent color

```
android:color="@android:color/transparent"
```

Comment: i've folllowed your instructions but it still doesn't work for me . It displays a black color